# Operating System material

Tags: operating-system, kernel

I want to understand what happens on the process stack,different segments etc when context switch between processes and threads happens. Basically i want to know how each segment is modified between context switches in concurrent programming. What is a best place to read about this? Can you suggest some tutorials or videos for Operating Systems?

I am not sure if i framed my question right,let me know.Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably best to just start reading the code for specific operating systems:

The Linux kernel's `kernel/sched.c` function [`sched_fork()`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+%2a/kernel/sched.c#L2972) is probably as good a place as any to start reading; it starts a brand new task, so I feel it gives you a good overview of the scheduler's internals and task memory management.

The FreeBSD's kernel's [`sys/kern/sched.c` function `sched_switch()`](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/kern/sched_ule.c?im=10#L1767) directly swaps between the current process and the next process; it is probably easier to read than the Linux variant.

Other operating systems may choose to handle context switches differently. (One of my managers [worked on an operating system that replaced the process table generic code with code to jump to the exact next task that would be scheduled](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.200.3019), among other cool run-time data-specific optimizations.)

The [FXR website](http://fxr.watson.org/) makes it really easy to follow 
code in a variety of operating systems. (Thanks Robert, if you're reading!) Out of the FXR list, I'd suggest studying Plan9, Minix, and OpenSolaris -- they are further from the FreeBSD tree than the other, more related, BSD-derived distributions.

Comment: Okay looks helpful. Thankyou. Do you go by the comments and understand the logic or go through the entire code logic really? I am afraid i cannot understand it all. Please suggest multiple things/articles like this. I really want to get a good over these topics

Comment: Updated to give link into the FreeBSD code too -- that's some seriously nice code. When it comes to comments vs code, I'm afraid you'll need to use both. The Linux kernel developers feel very strongly that the code should stand on its own and use comments only to point out subtleties. (It's a pretty strong rejection of Knuth's WEB programming ideals of detailed inline documentation.) If you look at only the comments, you'll miss the bulk of it, but if you skip the comments, you'll never understand why some things are the way they are...

Answer (score 0):

You asked a pretty loaded question. I recommend you start with a text book and work your way from there. A book almost ever Computer Science student uses is:

[Operating System Concepts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470128720)

Comment: i read that.but it definitely doesnt cove all those low level details right?

Answer (score 0):

Start with Intel System Programming Guides 3A if you want h/w level understanding. Then proceed to linux kernel source code and as told by sarnold.